# Google client.js Oauth2 refused to display iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

Background:
I am using Google client.js to access a cloud endpoints project that I created.
When the code executes, and returns the iFrame that should show the authentication confirmation, I get the error

> Refused to display "......" in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I know that this is a security feature to prevent malicious sideloading of content but I cant seem to figure out where I went wrong.

```
var CLIENT_ID = "this is my id";
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

function init() {
    var apisToLoad;
    var loadCallback = function() {
        if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
            signin(true, userAuthed);
        }
    };

    apisToLoad = 2; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
    apiRoot = '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';
    gapi.client.load('business', 'v1', loadCallback, apiRoot);
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', loadCallback);
}

signin = function(mode, callback) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES, immediate: mode},
        callback);
};

function userAuthed() {
    var request =
        gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
            if (!resp.code) {
                // User is signed in, call my Endpoint
                gapi.client.business.retrieve().execute(function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that i was using the wrong api key. If you run into this issue, use the proper api key.